# ruby // present or nil

Tags: ruby, syntax, conditional-statements

Simple example :

```
val = (params[:page] ? params[:page] : nil)
```

I just don't know how to name it, then can't find an better answer for it

I feel like a simpler syntax exists for this example; and would like to know how to write it better

Comment: *"I need the attribute to be really nil"* - what does `params[:page]` return?

Comment: Is this a Rails question?

Comment: As said below the example is not good; but what mischa answered was a simple and accurate answer. You might want to edit the question I guess

Comment: I would, but I have no idea what `params[:page]` could return (`nil`, `false`, empty string) or if this is related to Rails.

Comment: My question was really only about cleaning up this kind of syntax. what would the nil/false/empty would do ? What would be the syntax to choose depending on the value it has ?

Comment: It depends on what you consider "present". Maybe you should specify that.

Comment: Is saying "the params is in the url", or for a method "the option is passed",is more accurate ? I lack of vocabulary indeed :/ how would you ask ?

Comment: If `params` comes from a URL, I would mention the web framework I'm using (e.g Rails or Sinatra). Then I would provide a list of possible values for the `:page` parameter. Finally I would explain what I am trying to do with `params[:page]` and why I can't use it as it is. It's always easier to answer a question that's related to a problem you're actually facing.

Comment: I see; but as shivam said below, in my question I show the use of a ternary operator. What would be the name of the syntax provided by mischa ? If different

Comment: Yes, you provide an example with a ternary operator but you don't explain what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `||` like this:

```
val = params[:page] || nil
```

If `params[:page]` is `nil` or `false`, `val` will be `nil`. In all other cases it will be the value of `params[:page]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
val = params[:page]
```

You are using ternary operator, which means

```
condition ? true do this : false do this
```

Applying above to your example:

```
params[:page] ? params[:page] : nil
```

In Ruby any return value is treated as `true` except for `nil` or `false`. So here if `params[:page]` has a value (i.e. condition `true`) then you are assigning `val` its value. If its `nil`, you are assigning `val` as `nil`. So ultimately you are just assigning `val` whatever value `params[:page]` has. Hence `val = params[:page]`

Your latest example by this logic will simplify to:

```
%body{data: {page: params[:page]}}
```

> I need the attribute to be really nil; it would not be the case with
>   only :
>
> `%body{data: {page: params[:page]}}`

If `params[:page]` has no value, it will be `nil` by default. So your assumption is incorrect except incase of `false`.

Comment: Doesn't change anything.  By default, the [] method of a hash will return nil if the key isn't found.  You do not have to use the ternary operator.

Comment: His assumption is correct, because `params[:page]` could be `false` in which case it wouldn't be `nil`, but `false`.

Comment: @Mischa i had already discussed false condition in my answer. Anyways i have updated me statement again to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: But you don't offer any solution for that case, which is what he's asking for.

Comment: was not maybe the best example; but yep I felt like it was not enough to have the right "behaviour"

Comment: You made me doubt, but  you'll still have an empty attribute <body data-page> if the param is not in the url